# Power BI - How can I visualize percent of rows with a certain value and of those rows, percent with a value above or below a number?

Tags: database, database-design, powerbi

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx5Fw.png)

My data looks like this. I want to see a bar chart of the % of rows where column Y/N? contains "Y" and of those rows, the percent that % column contains a value of 7 or above, and the percent where % column contains a value below 7

Something like... 
IF [C2:C19] = Y, THEN COUNTIF [B2:B19] >=7
and
IF [C2:C19] = Y, THEN COUNTIF [B2:B19] <7

Sorry if this is unclear or an obvious question!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create three different measures 
first countrows with filter on "Y" and similarly others - then you can bring these values on your bar chart